# How to reference a data file not in a working directory

Tags: r

I'm using R and I know how to define a working directory:

```
setwd("C:/temp/")
```

I have a data file that is not in this folder.  How can I access it?  In SAS, it would be this:

```
libname x1 "C:\temp";
libname x2 "C:\temp\data folder";
```

Comment: In R you need to double-escape backslashes, so `"c:\\temp\\data folder"`. However, *even on Windows*, you can use forward-slashes, so `"c:/temp/data folder"` should still work.

Comment: Are you really asking how to import SAS datasets into R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem.

One is to save the current directory in a variable, temporarily change dir, then return to the current directory.

```
old_dir <- getwd()
setwd("C:/temp/data folder")

#code

setwd(old_dir)
```

Another is to use function `file.path` to make a fully qualified  file name.

```
path <- "C:/temp/data folder"
filename <- "datastuff.csv"
fullname <- file.path(path, filename)

fullname
#[1] "C:/temp/data folder/datastuff.csv"
```

Comment: +1 for the use of `file.path` ... using `setwd` each time can work but increases the odds of inadvertently being in the wrong directory. Perhaps `withr::with_dir(expr)` would be better, as it takes strong efforts to make sure that does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

one way is just with another line,

```
setwd("C:/temp/newfolder") 
read_csv(...)
```

and then again your original to get you back

```
setwd("C:/temp/")
```

In my opinion, `library(here)` is a nice one for easily setting relative paths and working up and down directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the absolute file path or the relative file path in the same way that you would use the file name if the file were in your current working directory.

For a file in your current working directory:

```
source("myFile.R")
```

For a file in a directory that is a peer to your current working directory:

```
source("../folder/myFile.R")
```

In this relative path, the `../` indicates "up one directory".  Relative file paths are relative to your current working directory.

For a file anywhere on your system:

```
source("C:/full/path/to/myFile.R")
```

Absolute paths start with `C:` on Windows, or `/` ("root") for *nix systems.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried and I got an error message.

    > source("C:/example/abc.sas7bdat") : 
     C:/example/abc.sas7bdat:2:1: unexpected input

Comment: What kind of file is `abs.sas7bdat`? Sounds like not an R code file, which is all `source(...)` should be used on.

Comment: You can't source a SAS dataset. Only text files with R commands in it.

Comment: Thank you (@rt2evans, @Tom), I understood.